# Nodejs mysql module returns records two time instead of one

Tags: mysql, node.js, module, node-modules

I am currently working on Node Js project and i am facing a problem that when i perform a query using connection from mysql module, i get results as records returned two time instead of one.

```
This is the code:
con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //Select only "name" and "address" from "customers":
        con.query("SELECT * FROM client", function (err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          for( i=0; i<result.length; i++ ){
              console.log("Code: "+result[i].code+" Nom: "+result[i].nom+" Prenom: "+result[i].prenom+" Ville: "+result[i].ville);
          }
        });
      });
```

> Code: 24 Nom: AHMADI Prenom: HAROUNI Ville: TANGER  
> Code: 25 Nom:
>   BENNANI Prenom: KENZA Ville: FES
>
> Code: 24 Nom: AHMADI Prenom: HAROUNI Ville: TANGER  
> Code: 25 Nom:
>   BENNANI Prenom: KENZA Ville: FES

Moreover, i am facing that problem either with functions calls or modules uses.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change variable result to variable fields emphasized text in loop and console.log. Here is a code.

```
con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //Select only "name" and "address" from "customers":
        con.query("SELECT * FROM client", function (err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Code: "+fields[i].code+" Nom: "+fields[i].nom+" Prenom: "+fields[i].prenom+" Ville: "+fields[i].ville);
        });
      });
```

Comment: The problem happened when i tried to print data on console but when i sent data to the browser it was fine and not duplicated. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Look, I update my answer. Try you use without loop in query

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be fine, because in my server it works despite I'm using promises. https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp Here you have an example of mysql just like yours that works. Isn't a problem in your DB?